# Send (g)ARP request to broadcast address using c++ on windows

Tags: c++, windows, arp

I want to send a broadcast ARP request with the destination address (255.255.255.255) on Windows 10 using c++. I am aware of the SendARP function, however, it does not work for broadcasting.

There is also other methods using winpcap and pcap headers, however, I need to do it without external libraries other than winsock. I tried to use

```
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,htons(0x0806));
```

But the socket is never valid on Windows. Is there a way to implement such broadcast ARP without the wnpcap library?

================

Methods tried:
SendARP works for sending ARP messages with specific destination IP address but not to a broadcast one

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-sendarp

The code in here didn't work for windows. I extracted and modified it, but either the socket is invalid or sendto function does not send the ARP request.
http://usuaris.tinet.cat/sag/send_arp.htm